# Error when trying to run project from Android Studio on my Nexus 6

Tags: android, compilation

I have my Nexus 6 connected via ADB and the Google USB driver is functional (I can run adb commands from command line) but when I try to compile my simple package on the device, it spits out this error:

`

```
02-02 13:38:26.091  12659-12659/com.jeremy.myfirstproject E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.jeremy.myfirstproject, PID: 12659
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.jeremy.myfirstproject/com.jeremy.myfirstproject.MyActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.jeremy.myfirstproject.MyActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.jeremy.myfirstproject-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2224)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2375)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5238)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.jeremy.myfirstproject.MyActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.jeremy.myfirstproject-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1065)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2214)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2375)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1293)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5238)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
    Suppressed: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.jeremy.myfirstproject.MyActivity
            at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method)
            at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:226)
            at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:219)
            at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:321)
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54)
            ... 14 more
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.jeremy.myfirstproject.MyActivity
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
            at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
            ... 13 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

`

Sorry about the wall of text. I'm not sure what the problem is here, maybe someone can sort it out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new project in Android studio and copy everything from the old project into the new one.

Comment: It`s awkward but does the job sometimes. Maybe it was a bad reference thru first time launching AS.

Comment: i tried this but i'm having an error `Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available`